# Which folder needs to be specified when selecting the location of the Android development SDK?

Tags: android, windows, sdk, livecode

When setting up your Mobile Support Preferences in LiveCode for developing to an Android , **which folder** within the **Android folder** archive needs to be selected? Whenever I select a folder it seems to come up with an error saying:

```
The chosen folder is not a valid Android SDK. 
Please ensure you have it installed correctly, 
and enabled support for Android 2.2 (Froyo).
```

I am running on Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

A few weeks ago there was an update to the Android SDK that had a new arrangement of files, which stopped LiveCode from being able to recognize the SDK. There are a couple of files that you can move across from the older SDK to work around the problem, but I believe the issue was fixed in LiveCode 6.0.2. So, try using that version of LiveCode.

Comment: Ok thank you so how do I need to reconfig my files in order for this to work?

Answer (score 1):

Got it resolved. My SDK was KitKat and live code is expecting Froyo. I checked Android 2.2 from SDK Manager and installed it. Then gave the path

F:\Android DK\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk

worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer here:
http://forums.livecode.com/viewtopic.php?f=53&t=20966

I had to download zipaling.exe and copy it to the tools folder inside my android-sdk folder.
I tried all other solutions on the internet, and this is all that worked for me.