# How do the files need to be reconfigured to allow LiveCode to work with an Android emulator?

Tags: android, windows, sdk, livecode

I was told in one of my other questions *(see: [Which folder needs to be specified when selecting the location of the Android development SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17389509/which-folder-needs-to-be-specified-when-selecting-the-location-of-the-android-de))* that in order to make my emulator work with LiveCode, I would need to reconfigure the files. One thing though, how?

Comment: Did you check if the problem still persists with LiveCode release 6.1 which was released today?

Answer (score 3):

Are you running the latest version of LiveCode (6.1)

If so, the latest Android SDK should be recognised without any issue.

The folder that you are looking to select is the root directory of the Android SDK. This is shown in the following image-

https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4Yzx.png