# How to create a Build for Android In LiveCode

Tags: android, livecode

When I try to set the location of the Android SDK in LiveCode's preferences window, I see the following error:

```
"The chosen folder is not a valid Android SDK. 
 Please ensure you have installed it correctly, 
 and enabled support for Android 2.2 (Froyo)."
```

After clicking OK in the dialog, the JDK field says (none). I have downloaded and installed Java (JDK 1.7.0_25) and [Android SDK 22.0.1](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html). What do I need to do?

Comment: Just to make sure that reviewers see this: this is a valid question for LiveCode programmers. Please, DO NOT CLOSE THIS QUESTION!!! If you decide to close it anyway, make sure to add your own comments before closing and explain how you would change this question!

Comment: Please refer to my exact same question here: *http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17431346/how-do-the-files-need-to-be-reconfigured-to-allow-livecode-to-work-with-an-andro*

Answer (score 0):

This is a very good question and LiveCode experts understand why you ask this. Thank you for asking.

It looks like you are not using the very latest version of LiveCode. Make sure you are using the GM and not the RC or DP of LiveCode 6.1. I just tried this and while the problem you describe occurs with all older versions, it doesn't occur with LiveCode 6.1.

Please, let me know if this answer is helpful. If not, then I'll help you with debugging the LiveCode IDE to find out what is wrong.

Comment: I have tried to install the live code in a system where already we are using the Android for development.it works there.But i think in my System there is some problem in JDK.

Comment: Please, confirm that you have LiveCode 6.1.0.2005 installed.

Comment: i manage to get path of JDK and now able to create .apk file of my Application.But now i am not able to open Amulator.

Comment: What did you do to get the path of JDK? We need to add this to the answer to make it complete.
You may also want to change the original question by adding "...and I can't start the Android emulator". Make sure to include a screenshot of the Android device image settings.

Comment: i have installed LiveCode6.0.2.But now after creating build i want to test it in emulator.so for that when i click AVD Manager.Its is not opening any window for creating emulator or can say it is not starting the emulator