# Livecode android sdk setup fails

Tags: android, livecode

https://livecode.com/app-in-a-day/installation/android/

http://lessons.livecode.com/m/2571/l/27389-how-do-i-become-an-android-developer-on-a-mac

explain how to setup the android sdk with LiveStudio on MacOs. I am using Android Studio Version 2.3.1 succesfully on Mac OS Sierra using the path Library/Android/sdk (relative to my home directory).

When I try to select that path for LiveCode Version 9.0.0 dp-6 in Mobile Support/Location of Android development SDK root
i get the message

```
"The chosen folder is not a valid Android SDK. Please ensure you have installed it correctly, and enabled support for Android 4.0.3 (API15)".
```

So i checked the installed SDKs platforms and Android 4.0.3 IceCreamSandwich API Level 15 Revision 5 is indeed installed.

The problem seems to haven been common in the past see e.g.

- http://forums.livecode.com/viewtopic.php?t=15215
- [Which folder needs to be specified when selecting the location of the Android development SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17389509/which-folder-needs-to-be-specified-when-selecting-the-location-of-the-android-de)

**What can I do about this with the current state of LiveCode and Android SDK versions?**

**Will this happen again on Android SDK changes?**

Answer (score -1):

You must use absolute path, not relative path.

It's a folder containing:

- add-ons
- docs
- platforms
- samples
- sources
- temp
- build-tools
- extras
- platform-tools
- SDK
- Readme.txt
- system-images
- tools

Comment: the sequence is start LiveCode 9.0  / New / Tablet Landscape / Settings / Mobile Support / Click "..." for Location of Android development SDK root
Therefore I donot have direct influence on whether the path is absolute or relative or do i?

Comment: You need just the SDK, not the full Android studio. You must give the SDK path.

Comment: It's a folder containing:
add-ons      
docs    
platforms       
samples         
sources        
temp
build-tools  
extras  
platform-tools  
SDK 
Readme.txt  
system-images  
tools